# Windows service with queing

Tags: c#

I need to develop windows service, functionality is it should fetch the data from SQLServer database on specific intervals (ex: Every 4.5 mins) and pushing into the Access2003 database.
But that access db is not always available, this is service needs to check the availability of access DB if it is there need to push the data.
In this case how better I can handle, using staging of DB tables or MSMQ.
Please guide me in this regard, if any samples plz provide me.
I'm using VS2008 version.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just keep fetching the data from SQL Server every interval and just write it to Access when it's available, so you don't need to store the data at all?

Comment: Like Grant said, and store the data in a queue until the AccessDB is available. Make sure to dump the queue to a data file in the OnStop() method, so that if the service is shutdown you don't lose any data (use a corresponding read in OnStart()).

Answer (score 0):

Use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) instead of coding everything by hand. That is, if you really have a SQL Server license (and not just the Express version).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a windows service you want. Are you sure you dont want to use the [Integration services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/integration.aspx) that come with Microsoft SQL Server?

In terms of the windows service approach, there are many parts to your question.

**Windows Service**

Visual Studio comes with a sample project for windows services. Have a look at that first to get to know about services and installers.

**Scheduler**

Check out http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ for a scheduling framework.

**AccessDB**

You would likely use the System.IO Namespace to check whether the access db is in the expected place. You could then interrogate the database using a LINQ to ODBC provider, or a LINQ to JET/OLEDB provider.